# wrap text is not working with reportlab SimpleDocTemplate

Tags: reportlab

Hi I am new to reportlab. i want to generate a pdf report which contains a table. some of the columns text in the table is greater than the column width now i want to wrap the text according to column width.

Following is the code i have written

```py
    # Imports
    from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
    from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
    from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
    from reportlab.lib.units import inch
    from reportlab.lib import colors
    from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Frame, Spacer, Image, Table, TableStyle, SimpleDocTemplate
    from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER
    
    # My data
    result1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]
    result2 = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
    result3 = [100,200,300,400,500,600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]
    
    # create a list and add the elements of our document (image, paragraphs, table) to it
    story = []
    
    # define the style for our paragraph text
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    styleN = styles['Normal']
    styleN.alignment = TA_CENTER
    styleT = styles['Title']
    styleB = styles["BodyText"]
    styleB.alignment = TA_LEFT
    
    # first add the Title of the report
    pTitle = Paragraph('<font size="30" color="darkblue">Report</font>', styleT)
    story.append(pTitle)
    story.append(Spacer(1, .5*inch))
    
    # User details
    story.append(Paragraph("<font color='darkblue'><b>Name : </b></font>" + "<user name>", styleN))
    story.append(Spacer(1, .1*inch))
    
    story.append(Paragraph("<font color='darkblue'><b>e-mail : </b></font>" + "<user email id>", styleN))
    story.append(Spacer(1, 1*inch))
    
    # Create Table
    tabledata = [[Paragraph('object',styleN),Paragraph('titletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitle',styleN),Paragraph('description',styleN),Paragraph('latitude',styleN),Paragraph('longitude',styleN),Paragraph('mywlink',styleN)],
                 [Paragraph(str(x),styleB) for x in result1],[Paragraph(str(x),styleB) for x in result2],[Paragraph(str(x),styleB) for x in result3]]#,
    
    
    colwidths = (80, 100, 100, 75, 75, 100)
    GRID_STYLE = TableStyle(
        [('GRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
         ('ALIGN', (1,1), (-1,-1), 'LEFT'),
         ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0), (-1,0), colors.darkblue)
    ]
        )
    t = Table(tabledata, colwidths, None, style=GRID_STYLE)
    
    
    ##t.setStyle(GRID_STYLE)
    t.hAlign='LEFT'
    story.append(t)
    story.append(Spacer(1,.5*inch))
    
    #build our document with the list of flowables we put together
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate('myReport.pdf',pagesize = letter, leftMargin=0.5*inch, topMargin=0.3*inch)
    doc.build(story)
```

Please help me in this issue and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

generally, Paragraph itself is actually a "word wrapped". If you use a more realistic test approach, per say, using [Loren Ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/) Texts. Then all the texts will be within the width of the column. So a word with such a long string is non practical.

Let's say, you do have a very long word, as shown above. There is still a way to do this. You'll need to define a wordWrap property for your style. Add the following code after your declare your styles.

```
styleB.wordWrap = 'CJK'
```

or

```
styleN.wordWrap = 'CJK'
```

WordWrap is set to 'CJK' to get Asian language linewrapping. This wordwrap just look for the end of the line and do the word-wrapping automatically.

For your solution, I'll use wordWrap 'LTR' for texts and wordWrap the long never ending number with 'CJK'

Answer (score 0):

```
#Following code will work with SimpleDocTemplate,Table, Paragraph

from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate 
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle`

#Below 2 line code is important in wrapping text

styles = getSampleStyleSheet() 
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name="ParagraphStyleName",alignment=TA_JUSTIFY,fontName= 
"Your-Font Name"))



#If your reading data from csv and adding to table follow the below code.
#or
#You can add your data to paragraph as shown below with paragraph style.
#Encoding used for mycode you can negelct it.

main_table_data=[]
with open("preinspection_checklist.csv",encoding="utf8") as f:
        csvdata=csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
        for row in csvdata:
        

             data=[
                Paragraph(row[0],styles["ParagraphStyleName"]),
                Paragraph(row[1],styles["ParagraphStyleName"]),
                Paragraph(row[2],styles["ParagraphStyleName"]),
               Paragraph(row[3],styles["ParagraphStyleName"]),
               Paragraph(row[4],styles["ParagraphStyleName"])
             ]

        
        
          main_table_data.append(data)



elements=[]
main_table=Table(main_table_data,colWidths= your_column_width,rowHeights= 
your_row_height,repeatRows=1)

#Here define your table style

main_table.setStyle(your_main_table_style)
elements.append(main_table)
pdf.build(elements)
```